# ASP.NET postback / redirect taking too long

Tags: asp.net, post, redirect

I've got a website that performs without issue on our dev servers, but the live website takes a long time (10 seconds+) to do a postback and redirect. I've used Profiler to view the database activity and enabling tracing on the website has not shown up any bottlenecks. The following page requests (all the same page) all take about 0.2 seconds to render according to the trace:

View product (GET) --> Add to basket (POST) --> Redirect --> View product (GET)

Any ideas where I should look next?

Comment: Can you trace traffic with fiddler to see how much traffic goes through the wire?

Comment: @DSharper - acccording to fiddler the postback sends 191 bytes and the page following the redirect 25,000 bytes, so not a great deal

Comment: did you checked DNS resolution time to your live server ?

Answer (score 1):

- Did you Checked the DNS resolution time for your live server.maybe tracert or ping might be helpful?
- how is your Uplink speed of your internet connection
- Can you trace with bandwidth monitor or tool like fiddler the traffic that get passed back and forth between your live site and the browser through internet wire.

If it is too much data that makes things slow,  try applying server generated traffic reducing techniques and client side caching techniques.

[image]

Comment: good point re. DNS / uplinks speed, I'll get that checked out

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned some below mentioned methods through that you can improvr website speed.

1. Compression of Web Pages (Use GZip)
2. avoiding inline styles
3. using external CSS & JavaScript documents
4. opting for a CSS/DIV based layout, instead of a table-based layout

Comment: My clients webserver / site follows items 2,3 & 4 above. No problem with the rest of the site though - just the postback / redirect